# send subview to back from storyboard ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, storyboard

Is there a way that I can add new `imageView` over all other views and send that view to back of my `viewController` directly from `storyboard`? I don't want to create `ImageView` in code and use `sendSubviewToBack` method for that.

Comment: You can just select the view and then go to 'Editor > Arrange > Send to back' or drag the view in the document outline so to be the first subview of your controller's main view.

Answer (score 17):

In Interface Builder check the left sidebar and you will see the view hierarchy as shown below.

Just add your view as normal, then drag it up the view hierarchy to the top of the list in 'View' and it will be at the bottom of the stack.

In the example below There is a container view in the root view controller view then Image View and then all the labels are 'on top' of that bottom image view.

[image: View hierarchy]

Answer (score 12):

Select the view in the Interface Builder, and then do **Editor** -> **Arrange** -> **Send to Back**

[image]

You can also rearrange the views in the view list in the left panel of the IB window. The views that are on top of that list will also appear on top in the app.