# Is it possible to sendSubview to back of an element created in storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface

I've programmatically created views and it's showing up on top of the elements I created in storyboard, I would like to send my views in the back (or bring my storyboard elements in front).

I can re-order my storyboard elements within storyboard or re-order my added views programmatically but I can't seem to find a way to re-order storyboard and added views between each other.

Before I create all elements programmatically (instead of storyboard) I was hoping there would be a solution or trick.

Currently the stack order of my view are as follow:

```
Storyboard View A
Storyboard View B
Storyboard View C
Programmatically view A
Programmatically view B
Programmatically view C
```

I can re-order them within storyboard or within programmatically:

```
Storyboard View A
Storyboard View C
Storyboard View B
Programmatical view A
Programmatical view C
Programmatical view B
```

What I'm inquiring is the possibility to:

```
Storyboard View A
Programmatical view B
Storyboard View B
Storyboard View C
Programmatical view A
Programmatical view C
```

Comment: What do u meant by re-order?

Comment: Create an Outlet for storyboard view? Then you can reorder it in code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [send subview to back from storyboard ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20570089/send-subview-to-back-from-storyboard-ios)

Comment: Do you know how to send your programmatically created views to the back? Perhaps your should [edit] your question to include some relevant code.

Comment: @Tj3n I've tried that and it wasn't working

Answer (score 0):

try the below code :

```
view.bringSubview(toFront: storyboardView)
```

storyboardView - the view which you want to bring front.

view - the view in which you subviews

Answer (score 0):

```
let newView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 120, width: 100, height: 200))
self.view.addSubview(newView)
self.view.sendSubview(toBack: newView)
```

this view goes behind everything created earlier.